# Avoid repetition of loop body before loop

Tags: python, loops

Ws you can see below, the code above and under the start of loop looks pretty much same. Is it possible to avoid this repetition?

Code:

```
term = ","
file_name = input("What is the file name? ")
f_extns = file_name.split(".")  #splitting file extension from file name
while term in file_name:
     print("Please type file name again with . not, ")
     file_name = input("What is the file name? ")
     f_extns = file_name.split(".")
else:
    print("The file extension is: " + repr(f_extns[-1]))
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response) See the [top answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23294659/4518341) under **Implementing Your Own Validation Rules**

Comment: Yeah, you can do it. Create a function that has the code in it, and just call it when you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
term = ","
while True:
    file_name = input("What is the file name? ")
    if term not in file_name: # If the user didn't input any commas
        print("The file extension is: ", file_name.rsplit('.')[0])
        break
    print("Please type file name again with . not, ")
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use an infinite loop and only break when the exit condition is met.

```
while True:
    file_name = input("What is the file name? ")
    f_extns = file_name.split(".")

    if term not in file_name:
        break
    else:
        print("Please type file name again with . not, ")
```

Comment: Oh this is much smarter

Comment: The `else` statement isn't necessary.

Comment: @AnnZen Quite true, but I generally lean towards including it to make the separation of the branches clearer.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your code by doing this

```
term = ","
file_name = input("What is the file name? ")
while term in file_name:
     print("Please type file name again with . not, ")
     file_name = input("What is the file name? ")
f_extns = file_name.split(".")
print("The file extension is: " + repr(f_extns[-1]))
```

This takes the input and as long as there is a comma in the input it will ask the user to repeat the filename. As soon as they enter a correct file name it will exit the loop and split by period.